# Unrecognized selector sent to instance (with UIBarButtonItem)

Tags: iphone, ios

In my iPhone application I have such code:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Instruction Controller";
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(menuButtonClicked)];   
}   


#pragma mark private methodes

-(void) menuButtonClicked{
    NSLog(@"menuButtonClicked");
}
```

But when I click on this button it raise an exeption: "Unrecognized selector sent to instance". How cam I resolve this issue?

**UPDATE**

2013-05-23 12:21:33.182 CICDP[3091:11603] -[__NSCFString menuButtonClicked]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8128eb0
2013-05-23 12:21:33.188 CICDP[3091:11603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString menuButtonClicked]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8128eb0'

Comment: What was the selector?

Comment: @selector(menuButtonClicked) - you can see it in my post

Comment: But what dos the error say in the console?

Comment: can you post the complete stacktrace? what instance, what selector were detected

Comment: I have provide you with it

Comment: i used your code it works for me...

Comment: how you declare your navigationController?

Comment: Wain probably has the answer. It's sending menuButtonClicked to an NSString...

Comment: How did you end up fixing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your controller class (the target of the button action) is being released before the button fires. The button is likely retained by its superview.

You need to do something to keep the controller class alive (some other instance needs to hold a strong reference to it) for the whole time the button is on display.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue but it wasn't a reference issue. The log 'Unknown class MyViewController in Interface Builder file.' helps me a lot.

I have solved this issue with the answer : [Xcode 6 Strange Bug: Unknown class in Interface Builder file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924966/xcode-6-strange-bug-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file)

To resolve this issue, be sure the module associated to your view is correctly set :

If you see Module None, there is the issue

[image]

Go on Module and just tap enter to see this :

[image]

Answer (score -3):

You need to add a : to the selector and change the method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Instruction Controller";

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
        initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self 
        action:@selector(menuButtonClicked:)];   

}

-(void) menuButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"menuButtonClicked");
}
```

Comment: the : in the selector is only optional. if you add one, the element returns reference for it self, but it also works fine if you use a selector without (id)sender ;)